# A multi-application of dijkstra's shortest path algorithm

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

We are given a single train in a graph that must traverse a sparse graph. The train always starts at Station 0. Each vertex in that graph is a "Station" and the edge is an adjacent track to another station. We assume that the train can go backwards as well as forwards. We are given a list of stations that contain a "car" and given how many cars. Each car has a destination it needs to get to and destinations of cars from the same station can be different. At most, a station will only have 5 cars and the maximum number of cars that our train can hold is 100. I am solving this by using dijkstra's to find the nearest station with a car and then finding a path to that car's destination. The problem is, it's a very inefficient way of going about this, because my train only holds and transports 1 car at a time. I want to be able to make full use of my train's capacity, but the problem I'm facing is that if I store more than one at a time, how would I choose the path that I go to? Does anyone have any good ideas?

The reason why it's not a minimum spanning tree problem is:

```
   .C.
  .   .
 .     .
A       B
```

If you specifically define a path, you would have to say that the path from A to B is the above path, which it's not.

Comment: Do you want a provably-optimal solution or just a better-than-what-you-have solution?

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, can I have both? I'd love to see what options I have for these conditions.

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't asking because I had both answers lined up or anything.  I just didn't want to waste your time with an approximate solution if you needed an exact solution (which sounded (and is) NP-Hard).

Comment: Give me whatever you got, I don't know enough to be picky.

Answer (score 4):

That's a [Vehicle Routing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem).

More specifically, this is the single-vehicle open static one-to-one capacitated pickup-and-delivery problem.

- Single vehicle: only one train
- Open: the vehicle is not required to return to the depot
- Static: all information is deterministic and known a priori
- One-to-one: each request originates at one location and is destined for
  one other location
- capacitated: the vehicles have limited carrying capacity
- pickup-and-delivery: a number of goods need to be moved from certain pickup locations to other delivery locations

This problem is NP-hard. Exact solutions are usually branch-and-bound
or branch-and-cut algorithms. Many approximation algorithms have been proposed for different variants, so I'll only give you some leads:

- [A Survey on Pickup and Delivery Problems](http://prolog.univie.ac.at/research/surveyPDP/) [Parragh, Doerner, Hartl 2008]
- [Single-Commodity Vehicle Routing Problem with Pickup and Delivery Service](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2008/697981/) [Martinovic, Aleksi, Baumgartner 2008]
- [Recent Models and Algorithms for One-to-One Pickup and Delivery Problems](http://www.diku.dk/~sropke/Papers/Recent%20Models%20and%20Algorithms%20for%20One-to-One%20Pickup%20and%20Delivery%20Problems_revised.pdf) [Cordeau, Laporte, Ropke 2007]
- [Static pickup and delivery problems: a classification scheme and survey](http://www.po.ufrj.br/projeto/papers/Static_pickup_and_delivery_Problems_a_classification_scheme_and_a_survey.pdf) [Berbeglia, Cordeau, Gribkovskaia, Laporte 2007]
- [NEO](http://neo.lcc.uma.es/vrp/vehicle-routing-problem/)
- [jsprit](http://jsprit.github.io/)

Comment: Thank you for the resources, I'm starting to see a couple possibilities that I can use. However, I'm a beginner programmer and it's very hard to read advanced research papers, are there references that are a little more user-friendly?